# Equivalent to dictionary d.items()[0] in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a large dictionary `d` and I want to display some random element (say my terminal will crash if I try to `__repr__` the whole thing).

In Python 2 I would call `d.items()[0]`; what do I do in Python 3 ... is the Pythonic equivalent `next(iter(d.items()))`?

Comment: define `some random element`

Comment: I mean any element i don't care which

Comment: Well, `d.popitem()` will remove an item from the dictionary, but will be fairly quick, compared to `.items()` methinks, perhaps even if you have to reinsert the key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The results of the two returned values are effectively equivalent, for `d.items()[0]` in Python 2 and `next(iter(d.items()))` in Python 3, however, this ignores a lot of subtleties.

`d.items()` creates a list of every single item in the list, effectively creating a shallow copy of the dictionary. It is effectively like:

```
def items(self):
    l = []
    for k, v in self.iteritems():
        l.append((k, v))
    return l
```

This is quite inefficient, since you are effectively duplicating a large number of items to extract a single item. A more efficient approach would be `next(d.iteritems())` in Python2.

Therefore, the following are much more "logically" equivalent, rather than superficially equivalent:

```
>>> # PY2
>>> d.items()[0]
>>> # PY3
>>> list(d.items())[0]
```

And:

```
>>> # PY2
>>> next(d.iteritems())
>>> # PY3
>>> next(iter(d.items()))
```

In short, your code will be a lot faster using the Python3 version, not to mention doing explicitly what the code states.

As noted in the Nathan's answer, in Python 3.7, dictionaries iterate in insertion order, meaning this will always return the first item added to the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

`next(iter(d.items()))` would be closer to equivalent to `next(d.iteritems())` in Python 2; closer to your original would be `list(d.items())[0]`. (The iter versions are both more efficient.)

However, the fact that dictionaries are unordered has always been an implementation detail - that is, not guaranteed - and it was [recently annouced](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html) that dictionaries will be deterministically ordered (by order of insertion) in Python 3.7 and beyond. Starting there, if you want a random item from a large dictionary you'll need to get it the hard way, with `random.choice(list(d.items()))`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @AlexanderHuszagh :)

Comment: I removed my comment and upvoted once I saw the correction :D. Excellent answer.