# Equivalent to list(d.items())[0] in Jinja2

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, jinja2

I switched from using Python2 to Python3 on the Ansible controller side.
I was using the expression `{{ osd['data_devices'].items()[0][0] }}` in a Jinja2 template loop `{% for osd in osd_spec %}` to get the key `paths` from the below dictionary:

```yaml
osd_spec:
   - spec_name: osd_spec1
     data_devices:
      paths:
      - /dev/sdg
      - /dev/sdh
   - spec_name: osd_spec2
     data_devices:
      paths:
      - /dev/sda
      - /dev/sdb
```

After switching to Python3 the expression did not work anymore and I am getting the error:

> dict_items object has no element 0

I then figured out that the `items()` function in Python3 returns a view object instead of a list and though, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48294434/equivalent-to-dictionary-d-items0-in-python-3), the output should be wrapped by a list.

Trying `list(d.items())[0][0]` in Python3 works as expected.
What would be the equivalent expression in Jinja2?

I tried `{{ osd['data_devices'].items() | list[0] }}`, but, this didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your dictionary, you could use the [`keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=keys#dict.keys) function and do:

```
{{ (osd.data_devices.keys() | list)[0] }}
```

Or use the [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists) filter and do:

```
{{ (osd.data_devices | dict2items)[0].key }}
```

---

As a demonstration, given:

```yaml
    - block:
      - debug:
          msg: >-
            {% for osd in osd_spec %}
            {{- (osd.data_devices | dict2items)[0].key -}}
            {% endfor %}

      - debug:
          msg: >-
            {% for osd in osd_spec %}
            {{- (osd.data_devices.keys() | list)[0] -}}
            {% endfor %}

      vars:
        osd_spec:
          - spec_name: osd_spec
            data_devices:
              paths:
              - /dev/sdg
              - /dev/sdh
```

It will yield:

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: paths

TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: paths
```

Answer (score 1):

Grouping the statement will do the job

```
{{ (osd.data_devices.items()|list)[0][0] }}
```

Defining a variable will also work

```
  {% set paths = osd.data_devices.items() | list %}
  {{ paths[0][0] }}
```